# How to remove id in documents before added to zip using php?

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am using ZipArchive() to zip a bunch of .txt,.pdf,.doc files together. Can someone please give me an example how to remove the ID from the beginning of all .txt,.pdf,.doc files before placing them in the zip?

for example:

```
144-a.txt
2-b.doc
25555-c.pdf
```

will be:

```
a.txt
b.doc
c.pdf
```

Comment: use rename function of php rename ("/folder/file.ext", "/folder/newfile.ext");

Comment: Can you please tell, how to remove the id in before the .txt,.pdf,.doc files

Comment: you just use explode function of php

Comment: you can use preg_replace in php...so that you can remove the numbers and symbols....

Comment: @Mahesh I just tried in google, but i couldn't find the exact thing. when i tried this code $filename = preg_replace('/^\d+_/', '', $row->filename); it is not getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the example code...try this

```
<?php
    $words ='3569_bcl-for-java-se-397068';
    $words1 =preg_replace('/^[0-9_]+/','',$words);
    echo $words1;
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you please tell for this code 3569_bcl-for-java-se-397068 actually this is a pdf file. For this i just need only the extension like .pdf. how i will get. Much appreciated if i get answer

Comment: $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: just give full filename in $filename..you will get that file extension...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, In web url it displaying tha file name as Apache-2.0.49.txt but while downloading the files it displaying the name as Apache-2.0.49.

Comment: you have to get tht filename using php....you have to use tht name only...

Comment: For this code Package_document/3899_In Detail_Search_page_4584.docx i need to remove  this thing 3899_